# Importing data from new excel files in a folder (new files added to the folder daily)

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to import data from several excel files located in the same folder. New files are added to the folder daily. I import the data once a week or month and need a loop that imports all data from files I haven't already imported from. Currently I have the following code I use, but I have to go in and retype the filename for every file to get new data. Help please?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:="H:\global\Prosjekt\NAS\RCL\OUTPUT-20150302.csv"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("yield1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Input").Select
Range("A9").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A9"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


Windows("OUTPUT-20150302.csv").Activate
ActiveWindow.Close

'XYZ
Sheets("Input").Select
 Range("R8:R204").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("XYZ").Select
   Range("xfd1:xfd197").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you wanted:

Durgun's answer in code:

```
Dim CurrentFilePath As Variant '<-- ADDED
Dim wkbOpenedWorkbook As Workbook '<-- ADDED
Dim SelectionB4 as Range '<-- ADDED
Const sDIR As String = "H:\global\Prosjekt\NAS\RCL\*.csv" '<-- ADDED, note: "*.csv" is filter for your files
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set SelectionB4 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))'<-- moved/changed, save reference to your 1 selection
CurrentFilePath = Dir(sDIR) '<-- ADDED
While CurrentFilePath <> "" '<-- ADDED
    Set wkbOpenedWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=CurrentFilePath) '<-- CHANGED, save reference to workbook, to close it later
    SelectionB4.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("yield1.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Input").Select
    Range("A9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A9"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


    wkbOpenedWorkbook.Close False '<-- CHANGED 'close and dont save, remove "False" to popup the save dialog

    'XYZ
    Sheets("Input").Select
     Range("R8:R204").Select
     Selection.Copy
     Sheets("XYZ").Select
       Range("xfd1:xfd197").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    CurrentFilePath = Dir(sDIR) '<-- ADDED
Wend '<-- ADDED
```

Note: there are many places in code to optimize, make more stable, faster, readable.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA there is a function named `Dir(pathname, attributes)`. 

You can find the reference here : [Function Reference](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Dir-Function-1a1a4275-f92f-4ae4-8b87-41e4513bba2e)

You are going to define a `FileList as Variant` and then set it with Dir function like this : `FileList = Dir("c:\YourFolder\)`

After that you can iterate through `FileList` for the Excel Files with a loop like this `While (FileList <> "")`

After reading file you can store which files you read in a text file so that you will not encounter with duplications.

Comment: You are welcome. You can select one of the answers as accepted by clicking the 'tick' at left of the answer to help others to see the correct answer too.